# KineticJS fillPatternImage not working since version 5.0

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs

Since I updated my KineticJS version to the latest (5.0.0) version filling a shape with a pattern image doesn't work anymore.

This is the code i am using to display the pattern:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: document.getElementById("stage"),
    height: 200,
    width: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var shape = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    fill: "red",
    fillPriority: "pattern"
});

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    shape.setFillPatternImage(image);
    stage.draw();
};
image.src = "http://placekitten.com/50/50";

layer.add(shape);
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ss3hF/

And a working example with old version: http://jsfiddle.net/ss3hF/1/

Does anyone else experience this?
Is it a bug or did i miss something in the ChangeLog?

Thanks in advance, McFarlane

Comment: Feedback: Works in IE11, fails silently (no errors, no image) in Chrome32 and Firefox26. Test further and then possibly report a bug :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
shape.setFillPatternImage(image);
shape.fillPatternScaleX(1);
shape.fillPatternScaleY(1);
stage.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks! Why? Is the fill pattern failing to initialize and this triggers it to apply--or something else?

Comment: I found that in last version of kineticjs (5.0.0) fillPatternScaleX and fillPatternScaleY equal 0 by default. Not shure is it bug or expected api changes.